# Save json to CoreData as String and use the String to create array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, core-data

I am creating an app for a radio station and I want to store "show" objects into an array. I use a webserver to supply json data to populate the array, but I want to store this json data into CoreData as a string so that access to the array doesn't depend on internet connection. Therefore, I want to update the string in CoreData on app launch, but create an array based off of the string stored in CoreData not on the json data from the webserver.

Here's my function to download the json data from the webserver and store it into a string:

```
func downloadShows() {
    let urlPath = "http://dogradioappdatabase.com/shows.php"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {return}

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }

        let jsonAsString = self.jsonToString(json: dataResponse)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

            let task2 = WebServer(context: context) // Link Task & Context
            task2.showsArray = jsonAsString
            print(jsonAsString)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}    

func jsonToString(json: Data) -> String {
    let convertedString: String

        convertedString = String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! // the data will be converted to the string
    return convertedString
}
```

Here's the function to create the shows array from the fetched json from CoreData:

```
    func createShowsArray () -> Array<ShowModel> {
    var array: Array<ShowModel> = Array()
    var tasks: [WebServer] = []

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        tasks = try context.fetch(WebServer.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }

    let arrayAsString: String = tasks[0].showsArray!
    print(arrayAsString)
    do {
        let data1 = arrayAsString.data(using: .utf8)!
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        array = try decoder.decode([ShowModel].self, from:
            data1)

    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }

    return array
}
```

However, this does not correctly load the data into an array. I printed the value I saved to CoreData in the downloadShows() function (jsonAsString) and got this as a response:

> [{"Name":"Example Show 2","ID":"2","Description":"This ...

But when I fetched the string from CoreData in the createShowsArray() function (arrayAsString), it had added "DOG_Radio.ShowModel"

> [DOG_Radio.ShowModel(Name: "Example Show 2", ID: "2", Description: "This ...

The JSON Decoder does not decode arrayAsString into an actual array. It throws this back:

> Error dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.})))

Sorry for the long question, I just don't know how to use CoreData to save json as String then convert that String into an array later

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bad practice to store json data or 'whole raw data' into CoreData. Instead Store the `Show` itself as a `NSManagedObject`.
You can do this by converting the JSON data to an Object (which it looks like you are already doing), then creating CoreData NSManagedObjects from them.

Realistically if you have no trouble converting the data from JSON there is no need to convert it to a string before saving to CoreData. You can simply store the `Data` as `NSData`, i.e. `transformable` or `binary data` and reconvert it later if your fetch to the server fails.

However, thats not that reliable and much harder to work with in the long run. The data could be corrupt and/or malformed.

In short, you need a Data Model and a JSON readable Data Structure you can Convert to your Data Model to for CoreData to manage. This will become important later when you want to allow the user to update, remove, save or filter individual `Show`'s.

`Codable` will allow you to covert from JSON to a Struct with `JSONDecoder().decode(_:from:)`.

**ShowModelCodeable.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct ShowModelCodeable: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var producer: String?
    var thumb: String?
    var live: String?
    var banner: String?
    var id: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case id = "ID"
        case description = "Description"
        case producer = "Producer"
        case thumb = "Thumb"
        case live = "Live"
        case banner = "Banner"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        description = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        producer = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .producer)
        thumb = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .thumb)
        live = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .live)
        banner = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .banner)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

    }
}
```

Next, We'll need a Core Data Stack and a CoreData Entity. Its very common to create a Core Data Stack as a Class Singleton that can be accessed anywhere in your app. I've included one with basic operations:

[image: Image of Core Data Model]

**DatabaseController.Swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DatabaseController {

    private init() {}

    //Returns the current Persistent Container for CoreData
    class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        return DatabaseController.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }


    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        //The container that holds both data model entities
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "StackOverflow")

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */

                //TODO: - Add Error Handling for Core Data

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }


        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    class func saveContext() {
        let context = self.getContext()
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("Data Saved to Context")
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                //You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    /* Support for GRUD Operations */

    // GET / Fetch / Requests
    class func getAllShows() -> Array<ShowModel> {
        let all = NSFetchRequest<ShowModel>(entityName: "ShowModel")
        var allShows = [ShowModel]()

        do {
            let fetched = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(all)
            allShows = fetched
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            //TODO: Handle Error
            print(nserror.description)
        }

        return allShows
    }

    // Get Show by uuid
    class func getShowWith(uuid: String) -> ShowModel? {
        let requested = NSFetchRequest<ShowModel>(entityName: "ShowModel")
        requested.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", uuid)

        do {
            let fetched = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(requested)

            //fetched is an array we need to convert it to a single object
            if (fetched.count > 1) {
                //TODO: handle duplicate records
            } else {
                return fetched.first //only use the first object..
            }
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            //TODO: Handle error
            print(nserror.description)
        }

        return nil
    }

    // REMOVE / Delete
    class func deleteShow(with uuid: String) -> Bool {
        let success: Bool = true

        let requested = NSFetchRequest<ShowModel>(entityName: "ShowModel")
        requested.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", uuid)


        do {
            let fetched = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(requested)
            for show in fetched {
                DatabaseController.getContext().delete(show)
            }
            return success
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            //TODO: Handle Error
            print(nserror.description)
        }

        return !success
    }

}

// Delete ALL SHOWS From CoreData
class func deleteAllShows() {
    do {
        let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShowModel")
        let deleteALL = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)

        try DatabaseController.getContext().execute(deleteALL)
        DatabaseController.saveContext()
    } catch {
        print ("There is an error in deleting records")
    }
}
```

Finally, we need a way to get the JSON data and convert it to our Objects, then Display it. Note that when the update button is pressed, it fires `getDataFromServer()`. The most important line here is

```
self.newShows = try JSONDecoder().decode([ShowModelCodeable].self, from: dataResponse)
```

The Shows are being pulled down from your Server, and converted to `ShowModelCodeable` Objects. Once `newShows` is set it will run the code in `didSet`, here you can delete all the Objects in the context, then run `addNewShowsToCoreData(_:)` to create new NSManagedObjects to be saved in the context.

I've created a basic view controller and programmatically added a tableView to manage the data. Here, `Shows` is your NSManagedObject array from CoreData, and `newShows` are new objects encoded from json that we got from the server request.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // Properties
    var Shows:[ShowModel]?

    var newShows:[ShowModelCodeable]? {
        didSet {
            // Remove all Previous Records
            DatabaseController.deleteAllShows()
            // Add the new spots to Core Data Context
            self.addNewShowsToCoreData(self.newShows!)
            // Save them to Core Data
            DatabaseController.saveContext()
            // Reload the tableView
            self.reloadTableView()
        }
    }

    // Views
    var tableView: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    lazy var updateButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.setTitle("Update", for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        b.isEnabled = true
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDataFromServer), for: .touchUpInside)
        return b
    }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.Shows = DatabaseController.getAllShows()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.register(ShowCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ShowCell.identifier)

        self.layoutSubViews()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //TableView -
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DatabaseController.getAllShows().count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // 100
        return ShowCell.height()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ShowCell.identifier) as! ShowCell

        self.Shows = DatabaseController.getAllShows()

        if Shows?.count != 0 {
            if let name = Shows?[indexPath.row].name {
                cell.nameLabel.text = name
            }

            if let descriptionInfo = Shows?[indexPath.row].info {
                cell.descriptionLabel.text = descriptionInfo
            }
        } else {
            print("No shows bros")
        }


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Show the contents
        print(Shows?[indexPath.row] ?? "No Data For this Row.")

    }

    func reloadTableView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    func layoutSubViews() {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let spacing: CGFloat = 8

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.view.addSubview(updateButton)

        updateButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        updateButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leftAnchor, constant: spacing * 4).isActive = true
        updateButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.rightAnchor, constant: spacing * -4).isActive = true
        updateButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: updateButton.bottomAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    }


    @objc func getDataFromServer() {
        print("Updating...")
        let urlPath = "http://dogradioappdatabase.com/shows.php"

        guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {return}

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
                guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }

            do {
                self.newShows = try JSONDecoder().decode([ShowModelCodeable].self, from: dataResponse)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }




    func addNewShowsToCoreData(_ shows: [ShowModelCodeable]) {

        for show in shows {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ShowModel", in: DatabaseController.getContext())
            let newShow = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: DatabaseController.getContext())

            // Create a unique ID for the Show.
            let uuid = UUID()
            // Set the data to the entity
            newShow.setValue(show.name, forKey: "name")
            newShow.setValue(show.description, forKey: "info")
            newShow.setValue(show.producer, forKey: "producer")
            newShow.setValue(show.thumb, forKey: "thumb")
            newShow.setValue(show.live, forKey: "live")
            newShow.setValue(show.banner, forKey: "banner")
            newShow.setValue(show.id, forKey: "id")
            newShow.setValue(uuid.uuidString, forKey: "uuid")
        }

    }



}
```

[image: View Hierarchy]

Comment: Why don't databases store all the records together as one big String? When you have many instances of a an object that are grouped in to an array it becomes impossible to read & manipulate a single record. One would have to pull every record from the database to alter a single record's attribute. Further, Attributes of Objects no longer retain their data type so a "3.14" is stored as a string rather than a double. As your needs for data management grow so does the demand for greater data organization, and the separations of concerns. For instance, passwords shouldn't be stored with names etc.

Comment: Perhaps a review of [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and Normal Forms would be appropriate, you shouldn't be at a point where synchronization between datasources is an issue. CoreData can automatically detect changes within `NSManagedObjects` and update them on the next save. If you have a JSON blob stored in core data that contains thousands of records and you want to change one attribute of one record you'll have to read the entire JSON file to manipulate it, then save the entire JSON blob back to core data.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with implementing CoreData. How would I update the objects stored in CoreData compared with the json data from the web server? I see in your answer that you use a function DatabaseController.deleteAllShows() and then save the shows to core data again. How would you delete all shows from CoreData (what does this function look like?)

Comment: @Evan I've added the `deleteAllShows()` class method to the database controller, Once you have the `NSManagedObjects` in your array you can access them and change them like normal array of objects i.e. `Shows[index].name = name`, then save the changes to CoreData by calling `DatabaseController.saveContext()` @Purpose, The question is about CoreData Object Management from JSON not `CloudKit`.

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you @RLoniello

Answer (score -1):

**Try this it's work for me**

```
// Convert JSON to String
func jsonToString(json: AnyObject)->String{
    do {
        let data1 =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) // first of all convert json to the data
        let convertedString = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) // the data will be converted to the string
        return convertedString! // <-- here is ur string

    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }

    return ""
}

// Convert JSON String to Dict
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> NSDictionary!{
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {

            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```